# Does enum means static class?

Tags: java, enums

I have a confusion here.

If I cannot declare a class as static, how does **enum** works?
It looks like a static class, because it gets instantiated itself and can be called anywhere.
Looks like I can use enum almost like other **static fields**.

Is it safe to use **enum**?

Comment: you can create nested static class

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`enum` types are automatically static.  You can't have a non-`static` enum, so the `static` is implied.

[JLS 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

Comment: ahh. I didn't know that. Even after 2 years, I sometimes feel I don't know java ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each enum which you are declaring inside an enum type is static member of your enum type.And the type of your enum variables is the type of your enum,in short they are self typed.